# Multiple Image Uploader Using jQuery and Asp.net C#

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I am looking for a multiple image uploader using jQuery or Ajax that show me thumbnails while uploading images, and having awesome look.. I suffer internet too much to download any code but I found only files that interact or Works with open source server-side platforms like (PHP, Python, Ruby on Rails, Java, Node.js, Go etc.)

Following is a link

```
http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/
```

any links or suggestions will be warm welcomed..

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

The file upload you link to shows thumbnails, and has been used with ASP.Net. I have implemented it successfully, and the [wiki](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki) for the project links to pages showing how it has been implemented in .NET, along with code samples.

If you can't download a code sample, you can always browse the source of [this example](https://github.com/maxpavlov/jQuery-File-Upload.MVC3) on Github which uses MVC3.

Comment: nice inforamtion from your side.. but am not following MVC3 archetecture but Entity Framework or you can say N-Tier architecture

Comment: also it sowing Error: Internal Server Error

Comment: MVC and Entity Framework are completely different things Raavi. MVC is a web app framework whereas Entity Framework is an [object relational mapper](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) for persisting data in a database. On the wiki for the project there are non-MVC examples, such as using an IHttpHandler [here](https://github.com/timabell/jQuery-File-Upload/tree/dotnet).

Comment: @ Steve Kennarid! thanks for this help, one thing more, i download files from your last link, and open it as a web site, after run/debug it,when i upload file it dosent work , so it shows Error: true. any suggestions plz...

Comment: although after reviewing this project, am getting an error:

"Unexpected token <"

Answer (score 0):

http://www.uploadify.com/demos/

Check this site. It seems good and easy.

Comment: it seems good, but i want hat show me thnumnails of pictures that are going to upload while uploading images and after it

Comment: Oops sorry. I missed that part.